# VBA Database search code

Tags: database, excel, vba

So I am currently working on a database search application in excel, and I unfortunately cannot get my code to run properly. The error that is preventing my program from running is  "Loop without do" on the end sub of my main code. I have tried adding it everywhere, and if i get rid of the loop then I receive a do without loop error.

```
Sub FindGame()

Worksheets("DATA").Activate

Dim month As Range
Dim database As Range
Dim day As Range
Dim time As Range

Set database = Worksheets("DATA").Range("A4:D42")
Set month = Worksheets("DATA").Range("B4:B42")
Set day = Worksheets("DATA").Range("C4:C42")
Set time = Worksheets("DATA").Range("D4:D42")



    i = 1
    RowStart = 0
    RowEnd = 0


    If frmPreference.optDOW.Value = True Then
        'sort by Month and then by day of the week
        Range(database).Sort Key1:=Range(month), Order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range(day), order2:=xlAscending
        With Range(database)
        Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
            For i = 5 To 42
                If Cells(i, 1) = xmonth Then
                    If day = "Sunday" Then
                        RowStart = i
                        Do While Cells(i, 1).Value = xmonth
                            i = i + 1
                        Loop
                        RowEnd = i - 1
                        Exit Do
                    ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = day Then
                        RowStart = i
                        Do While Cells(i, 1).Value = xmonth
                            If Cells(i, 2).Value <> day Then
                                RowEnd = i - 1
                                Exit Do
                            End If
                            i = i + 1
                        Loop
                        RowEnd = i - 1
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Loop

    If frmPreference.optGameTime.Value = True Then
        'sort by month and then by time
        Range(database).Sort Key1:=Range(month), Order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range(time), order2:=xlAscending
        Worksheets("DATA").Activate
            Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
                If Cells(i, 1) = xmonth And Cells(i, 3).Value = GTime Then
                    RowStart = i
                    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value = xmonth
                        If Cells(i, 3).Value <> GTime Then
                            RowEnd = i - 1
                            Exit Do

                        End If
                        i = i + 1

                     Loop
                    RowEnd = i - 1
                    Exit Do

                End If

                i = i + 1
            Loop
    Worksheets("Welcome").Activate

    Call DisplayProduct

End Sub
```

Comment: **WHAT** is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: And could you please remove all code from your example that is not necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: This is a job for `MS-Access`! You can link your excel sheet to the ms access database and then use a form for the search very easy, without  vba.

Comment: @DirkReichel So i just removed all the unnecessary code aside from the one that is giving me the error. I don't understand why i am getting this "Argument not Optional" error. This won't let the rest of my program run

Comment: Is a line highlighted for this error? Looks like [`Month`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s70thwaz(v=vs.90).aspx) is the problem... it is a buildin function of vba... try rename it to `xMonth` or whatever and test it again...

Comment: @jr144144: I suggest you use @user3598756 approach on `Day = cmbDOW.Value` as that would be neater. However, if *do* need to validate the day (as per @DirkReichel suggestion), then you might as well also validate the month. And what is `DOW` and `GT`? Neater naming conventions will help, and add some indentation.

Answer (score 0):

don't catch the big picture, but I'd say you haven't defined any variables named after `Sunday`, `Monday`, etc., so that you want to use:

```
If cmbDOW.Value = "Sunday" Then
        Day = "Sunday"
```

but should this be the real case, then you could "collapse" the entire block:

```
    If cmbDOW.Value = Sunday Then
        Day = "Sunday"
    ElseIf cmbDOW.Value = Monday Then
        Day = "Monday"
    ElseIf cmbDOW.Value = Tuesday Then
        Day = "Tuesday"
    ElseIf cmbDOW.Value = Wednesday Then
        Day = "Wednesday"
    ElseIf cmbDOW.Value = Thursday Then
        Day = "Thursday"
    ElseIf cmbDOW.Value = Friday Then
        Day = "Friday"
    ElseIf cmbDOW.Value = Saturday Then
        Day = "Saturday"
    End If
```

to simply:

```
        Day = cmbDOW.Value
```

Comment: The OP still would need the check for `cmbDOW.Value` to be a weekday (if it could be something different). Also `Day` is a buildin function of vba and will lead to problems if used as a variable!

Comment: @DirkReichel: That's untrue! You can declare Day as a string, and it will work fine as a string.

Comment: I never said it is impossible. But your vba will mess up... not that much... but you will notice troubles... Not having a restriction doesn't means that it is smart to do it.